# Next.js - It is possible to make an app with next.js and an another server for backend application and be always good for SEO performances?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

All is in the title:

It  is possible to make an app with Next.js coupled to an another server for backend application and be always good for SEO performances ?

I'm trying to build an app with socket.io in Next.js. Seems I got to build an another server specifically for socket.io. By the same way Iwill use this server to handle databases requests and all.

I wonder if it always great for SEO performance to do that ? I mean, if SEO is good since my UI content will appear to crawler thanks to Next.js.

Any hint would be great, 
Thanks

Comment: You can implement a [custom server](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-server-and-routing) in NextJS - it's just an express app so it can do whatever NextJS can. For example, [handle SocketIO](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express)

Comment: okay I see, thanks, and please, do I have to reset the server side rendering on the custom server or NextJS handle that underground ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good to separate to backend server and frontend server.

- backend server (restful API/websocket/...): connect to database, do business logic and serve data for the client. The clients consuming this API include both server (server rendering) and client (client-side react application).
- frontend server (next.js): Next.JS app helps you build a universal app which both render from serverside and clientside.

About socket.io, The mechanism of it is asynchronous. Emit event and listen to event are the two different things. I think it's only suitable for client side. You can use it for getting realtime data, update UI realtime. If the content need to be served for SEO, you should use RESTful API which help your app easily getting and prerender from server.

Comment: Hi Dat Tran and thank. If I understand you SEO is still possible with this configuration on the principle

Comment: Yes. It's possible. But the data served for SEO should be from Restful API. You should use SOCKET.IO for the ones can be loaded later from client side only.

Comment: Another question please, in terms of performance do you know if it is performance costly to have two servers or not a very question to put on balance for a classic Web App of 15-30 pages max

Comment: If your web app is small. I don't think There's any performance problem. There's only 1 problem but It's about react server-rendering itself which is that It's quite slow when the traffic is super large. But for sure, There're also solutions for them. One more thing is that, if your website is small and you still want to have separated backend and frontend, you can still put both services in the same server.

Comment: @Webman if you think mine answers your question, please accept it.